# Is there a function to recognize a word?

Tags: r

Is there a way to evaluate a string and see if it evaluates to a word in English?  Here is what I am looking for

```
is.word("hello world")
[1] FALSE

is.word(c("hello", "world")
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

The above does not work as there is no `is.word` logical function.

Comment: You would need an English dictionary of words to check against.

Comment: What exactly do you consider a word? What about "selfie", "l8tr", "hola", "o"?

Comment: as Pierre pointed out, I need to evaluate if this is a valid English word. A solution was suggested to look for string without space and call it a word. That is nice to know but not what i am looking for.

Comment: So what have been your attempts at a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, you need an English dictionary to match against. The `GradyAugmented` object in the `qdapDictionary` package is one such dictionary:

> A dataset containing a vector of Grady Ward's English words
> augmented with ‘DICTIONARY’, Mark Kantrowitz's names list, other
> proper nouns, and contractions.

```
library(qdapDictionaries)
is.word  <- function(x) x %in% GradyAugmented
is.word(c("hello world"))
## [1] FALSE
is.word(c("hello", "world"))
## [1] TRUE TRUE
is.word(c("asfasdf"))
## [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

**No, there is no such function in R**.

Although you can easily implement naïve approach that will work in 9 out of 10 cases.

### Custom solution

First of all, you need a dictionary of "words" that you will match your data against. One such dictionary is compiled by GNU people and distributed under open source license at [SCOWL (And Friends)](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) website.

Download data file and unzip it. Words are scattered across multiple files with suffix indicating region, category and commonness (or probability that everyday English user will not be familiar with word). Using `list.files()` function with `pattern` argument, or `grepl()` function, you can select exact set of dictionaries that you care about.

```
# set path to extracted package
words.dir <- '/tmp/scowl-2015.08.24/final/'
words <- unlist(sapply(list.files(words.dir, pattern='[1-6][05]$', full.names=TRUE), readLines, USE.NAMES=FALSE))
# For some reason most frequent words are not in "final" dir…
words <- c(words, readLines(paste0(words.dir, '../r/special/frequent')))
length(words)
# [1] 143681
```

Then verifying if word is English is as easy as checking if it exists in vector of known words. The nice thing is that you get vectorization for free.

```
c("knight", "stack", "selfie", "l8er", "googling", "echinuliform") %in% words
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
```

### Core problem

The real problem is "what counts as word?". Does "googling" count as word? It is commonly used now, but that wasn't a case 15 years ago. And what about "[echinuliform](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/echinuliform)"? I guess that plenty of native speakers wouldn't understand it.

Discussing this issue falls outside of scope of this website, but there is some arbitrariness in language and currently no computer program is able to cope with that.

Comment: "echinuliform" at courtesy of [Dictionary of Unusual Words](http://phrontistery.info/ihlstart.html).