# How can I assess if a character string is an English word in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of character strings:

```
my.words <- c("Alexandria", "zrfos")
```

I want to check if each is a valid English word.

In the above cases, I would expect the following output:

```
IsEnglishWord(my.words)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Any possible idea how I could do that?

Comment: If on linux, you might look at the OS-level `dict` package that pre-installs a dictionary of sorts and you can do simple lookups (I haven't googled enough to find a windows variant of `dict`, perhaps that's on you to research). I suspect that this is probably better, as any net-based is going to be prone to rate-limiting and/or DoS on the server (if you don't manage your lookups well).

Comment: One of your biggest problems researching this will be that a "dictionary" in CS terms is a key/value store (R does it with named lists or environments). Good luck.

Comment: Well, it's kind of unfortunate that this got closed, as I wrote a 6 line cross-platform answer for it. Here's an answer to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515914/13095326